# Passing multiple URLs into a dict and extracting data

Tags: python, api, loops, dictionary, url

I generated the following code where I pass multiple URLS via API and ask that there be an output written to different pandas dataframes. It (sort of) works, but the outcome is incorrect

1) It seems to enter the function and print "Success" way too many times. Why?

2) The output for all the dataframes is the same; not sure where the error is.

See the function:

```
def data_extract(url):
payload = {'limit':'200000'}

# Persists parameters across requests
s = requests.Session()

# To determine success of request, and error code
for url in url:
    try:
        response = s.get(url)      
        # If the response was successful, no Exception will be raised 
        response.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError as http_err:
        print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')
    else:
        # Ret
        jsonData = s.get(url, params=payload).json()
        print('Success!')

df_tmr = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['records'])
return df_tmr
```

See the call to the function:

```
    urls = {
    # Rainfall data
    'tot_rain_mth': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/5942f8bd-4240-4f68-acd2-a5a276958237/resource/778814b8-1b96-404b-9ac9-68d6c00e637b/data',
    'no_days_rain_mth': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/rainfall-monthly-number-of-rain-days/resource/8b94f596-91fd-4545-bf9e-7a426493b674/data',
    'max_rain_mth': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/rainfall-monthly-maximum-daily-total/resource/df4d391e-6950-4fc6-80cd-c9b9ef6354fe/data',
    # Temperature Data
    'mean_sun_dur_mth': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/sunshine-duration-monthly-mean-daily-duration/resource/0230819f-1c83-4980-b738-56136d6dc300/data',
    'wet_bulb_hr': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/wet-bulb-temperature-hourly/resource/0195dc7a-2f49-4107-ac7c-3112ca4a09a8/data',
    'min_air_temp_day': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/surface-air-temperature-mean-daily-minimum/resource/ad0d8a97-9321-42e9-ac6f-46bf12845d44/data',
    'min_air_temp_mth': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/surface-air-temperature-monthly-absolute-extreme-minimum/resource/0c5b9752-2488-46cc-ae1c-42318d0f8865/data',
    'mean_air_temp_mth': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/surface-air-temperature-monthly-mean/resource/07654ce7-f97f-49c9-81c6-bd41beba4e96/data',
    'max_air_temp_day': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/surface-air-temperature-mean-daily-maximum/resource/c7a7d2fd-9d32-4508-92ef-d1019e030a2f/data',
    'max_air_temp_mth': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/air-temperature-absolute-extremes-maximum/resource/96e66346-68bb-4ca9-b001-58bbf39e36a7/data',
    # Humidity Data
    'min_hum_mth': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/relative-humidity-monthly-absolute-extreme-minimum/resource/585c24a5-76cd-4c48-9341-9223de5adc1d/data',
    'mean_hum_mth': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/relative-humidity-monthly-mean/resource/4631174f-9858-463d-8a88-f3cb21588c67/data',
    'mean_hum_yr': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/relative-humidity-annual-mean/resource/77b9059f-cc9a-4f4f-a495-9c268945191b/data' 
}

df={}
for i in range(len(urls.keys())):
    df[str(i)] = pd.DataFrame()
#print('Name of Dataframe:', df)
    df[str(i)] = data_extract(urls.values())
print (df['0'])
print (df['1'])
```

--> Sorry about the bad formatting; cant quite get it right in SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
def data_extract(url):
  print(url)
  payload = {'limit':'200000'}
  s = requests.Session()
  try:
      response = s.get(url)      
      response.raise_for_status()
      jsonData = s.get(url, params=payload).json()
      print('Success!')
  except Exception as err:
      print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')      

  df_tmr = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['records'])
  return df_tmr

urls = {
    # Rainfall data
    'tot_rain_mth': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/5942f8bd-4240-4f68-acd2-a5a276958237/resource/778814b8-1b96-404b-9ac9-68d6c00e637b/data',
    'no_days_rain_mth': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/rainfall-monthly-number-of-rain-days/resource/8b94f596-91fd-4545-bf9e-7a426493b674/data',
    'max_rain_mth': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/rainfall-monthly-maximum-daily-total/resource/df4d391e-6950-4fc6-80cd-c9b9ef6354fe/data',
    # Temperature Data
    'mean_sun_dur_mth': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/sunshine-duration-monthly-mean-daily-duration/resource/0230819f-1c83-4980-b738-56136d6dc300/data',
    'wet_bulb_hr': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/wet-bulb-temperature-hourly/resource/0195dc7a-2f49-4107-ac7c-3112ca4a09a8/data',
    'min_air_temp_day': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/surface-air-temperature-mean-daily-minimum/resource/ad0d8a97-9321-42e9-ac6f-46bf12845d44/data',
    'min_air_temp_mth': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/surface-air-temperature-monthly-absolute-extreme-minimum/resource/0c5b9752-2488-46cc-ae1c-42318d0f8865/data',
    'mean_air_temp_mth': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/surface-air-temperature-monthly-mean/resource/07654ce7-f97f-49c9-81c6-bd41beba4e96/data',
    'max_air_temp_day': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/surface-air-temperature-mean-daily-maximum/resource/c7a7d2fd-9d32-4508-92ef-d1019e030a2f/data',
    'max_air_temp_mth': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/air-temperature-absolute-extremes-maximum/resource/96e66346-68bb-4ca9-b001-58bbf39e36a7/data',
    # Humidity Data
    'min_hum_mth': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/relative-humidity-monthly-absolute-extreme-minimum/resource/585c24a5-76cd-4c48-9341-9223de5adc1d/data',
    'mean_hum_mth': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/relative-humidity-monthly-mean/resource/4631174f-9858-463d-8a88-f3cb21588c67/data',
    'mean_hum_yr': 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/relative-humidity-annual-mean/resource/77b9059f-cc9a-4f4f-a495-9c268945191b/data' 
}

df={}
temp = list(urls.values())
for i in range(len(temp)):
    df[str(i)] = data_extract(temp[i])

print(df['0'])
print(df['1'])

if len(df) == len(temp):
  print('success')
```

I think this will help you. You where iterating over all items and returning only last item as you. Just need to remove for loop from data_extract method.

Comment: Hello @SahilDesai,

Great, thanks for being so quick - I will update this post, once I have checked that all the data is accurate